# Different MSI files with the same product code

Tags: windows-installer, installation

Is it possible - following two different MSI files - to have the same product code and installed on the same machine?

Comment: The same product name can show up several times in Add / Remove programs if they have different product codes and the major upgrade failed so older versions were not uninstalled when the newer one was installed. This is what might have happened if you saw two versions of the same product in Add / Remove programs. If the product code would have been the same for both versions, you would get a warning that the product is already installed.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible and will result in error message 1638 stating that another version of the program is already installed.